# how to filter an array by index which is given as an array

Tags: javascript

I want to filter this array by index?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I am trying to use

```
arr.filter(x => x === [2,3])
```

but it does not seems to work?

I want only [2, 3]rd index?

Answer (score 3):

You need `map` here rather than `filter`:

```js
arr = [11,22,33,44,55,66];
indexes = [2,3]
result = indexes.map(i => arr[i])
console.log(result)
```

Note that this returns values in the `indexes` order, but if `indexes` are unsorted and you need values in the source order, then you indeed need `filter`. Consider:

```js
arr = [11,22,33,44,55,66];
indexes = [4,2]

result1 = indexes.map(i => arr[i])
result2 = arr.filter((_,i) => indexes.includes(i))

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: The only answer that didn't get misled by the OP's use of `filter`, resulting in a very obvious and clean solution.

Comment: @Cerbrus: they are actually different, depends on what exactly the OP wants.

Comment: Considering the simple sample data, I doubt the ordering matters, but ok. (Even then, if sorting matters, it's probably more efficient to just sort the indexes array and then `map`)